# Indigo ros_core source compile error in actionlib_msgs

Tags: ros, build-from-source, debian, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm compiling indigo-ros_core from source on Debian and I'm getting stuck at actionlib_msgs with the following error:

```
<== Finished processing package [43 of 63]: 'std_msgs'

==> Processing catkin package: 'actionlib_msgs'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/src/common_msgs/actionlib_msgs -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/actionlib_msgs -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/build_isolated/actionlib_msgs'
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/actionlib_msgs
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/build_isolated/actionlib_msgs/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/build_isolated/actionlib_msgs/cmake/actionlib_msgs-genmsg.cmake:3 (message):
  Could not find messages which
  '/home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/src/common_msgs/actionlib_msgs/msg/GoalStatusArray.msg'
  depends on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

  Cannot locate message [Header] in package [std_msgs] with paths
  [['/home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs/share/std_msgs/cmake/../msg']]
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/crunchex/uproot/iso_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/genmsg/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:304 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (generate_messages)
```

At this point, I've already finished processing std_msgs, which is where the Header message is defined. So I'm not really sure why it would be failing at this point. Anyone have a clue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221532/indigo-ros_core-source-compile-error-in-actionlib_msgs/) by [crunchex](https://answers.ros.org/users/25178/crunchex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 376 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-28**:
Not a solution, just a fyi: there is a packaging effort for Debian underway at [DebianScience/Robotics/ROS](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Robotics/ROS). Might save you some time/trouble.

**Comment by [crunchex](https://answers.ros.org/users/25178/crunchex/) on 2015-11-28**:
Great! Thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a workaround to the problem, but I think there is still some sort of bug in the actionlib_msgs dependencies.

Since my original command, part of the official Debian Indigo installation process, is this:

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
```

The packages that were built successfully up to the point where actionlib_msgs fails, will make it into `/opt/ros/indigo`. If I source that workspace and try the same command again, then the build will work fine (63/63). Not sure why this is.

**Update**: turned out to be a permissions thing. This answer pointed me in the right direction: http://answers.ros.org/question/59178/catkin_make_isolated-fails-with-install-space-optrosgroovy/?answer=59180#post-id-59180

---

Originally posted by [crunchex](https://answers.ros.org/users/25178/crunchex/) with karma: 376 on 2015-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug is annoying. I spend quite a bit time trying to solve it but I the easiest way to solve it finally was to add a symbolic link of the std_msg folder in the devel isolated space. I mean:

> $ ln -s src/std_msgs/msg   devel/std_msgs/share/std_msgs/cmake/../msg

Not too much pretty but at least it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dimdim](https://answers.ros.org/users/28110/dimdim/) on 2016-09-29**:
this work, thnx
from this ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/common_msgs/ to
[['~/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/std_msgs/share/std_msgs/cmake/../msg']]

for
sudo catkin_make_isolated --install
ln -s ...  5-6 times
result:
Finished processing package [204 of 204]: 'xacro'

**Comment by [J.C.](https://answers.ros.org/users/84658/j.c./) on 2022-03-04**:
soft link failed, I have to copy this folder then it works. Thanks